# How can I get mouse input but the mouse still effect the desktop?

Tags: java

How can I get mouse co-ordinates when I click but still have the click effect the desktop?

I currently have a transparent frame which gives me the co-ordinates of the clicks but I need clicks to effect the desktop. If I set the opacity of the frame up under 0.10 I can click the desktop but I do not get mouse co ordinates. Any suggestions?

```
Runnable thread = new Runnable() {
  public void run() {        
    setTitle("979");        
    setSize(screen.width, screen.height);

    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(transFlo);          
    stopRecording.setBackground(Color.red);

    add(mousePosLabel);
    add(stopRecording); 

    setOpacity(0.05f);        
    setVisible(true);
  }
};
```

Is it possible to do it with a transparent JFrame, or a screenCapture or anything?

Answer (score 1):

Use class `java.awt.Robot`. 
When your transparent window is clicked you can disappear it and emulate click on the same point using robot. Then create transparent window again.